# Symfony REST API and Entity Hierarchy

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am not getting all the attributes I would like to get serialized with FOSRestBundle.
I'll try to simplify in the following example:

Imagine I have the following Entity Inheritance.

```
class Vehicle
{
    private $id;
    private $numberOfWheels;
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
    private $numberOfDoors;
}

class MotorBike extends Vehicle
{
    private $handleBar;
}
```

If i do the following:

```
$myTransport = new MotorBike();
$myTransport -> setNumberOfWheels(2);
$myTransport -> setHandleBar("low");
```

When I try to serialize $myTransport with FOSRestBundle in a Controller I am only getting Vehicle attributes:

```
$view = View::create()->setFormat('json');
$view ->setData($myTranport);
return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
```

This is what I am getting:

```
{
 id: 1,
 wheels: 2
}
```

Instead of getting all MotorBike attributes:

```
{
 id: 1,
 wheels: 2
 handleBar: "low"
}
```

How can I get all attributes?
I also tried setting attributes as protected, but same result.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOSRestBundle was working fine. The problem was I forgot to refresh the database/ORM with last changes. This did the trick:

```
console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Kind Regards.